# Objective -C vs. Swift Custom Initializers

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am working on a Swift project with custom classes.  The old Objective-C version of the project had a custom init method shown below.

Custom init from custom class

```
-(id) initWithURLDictionary: (NSDictionary *) dictionary{
self = [super init]; 
if (self) {
    self.URLDictionary = dictionary;
}
return self;
```

}

When using this class I would create the object with the custom initializer and then set the delegate for the custom class to self.

```
// Create a temporary dictionary of the feeds, allocate and initialize the FLODataHandler object and set the delegate (me) to self.
NSDictionary *URLTempDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: kFLOCyclingURL, @"FLO Cycling", kTriathleteURL, @"Triathlete", kVeloNewsURL, @"Velo News", kCyclingNewsURL, @"Cycling News", kRoadBikeActionURL, @"Road Bike Action", kIronmanURL, @"Ironman", nil];
self.dataHandler = [[FLODataHandler alloc] initWithURLDictionary: URLTempDictionary];
self.dataHandler.delegate = self;
```

In Swift I am a bit confused.  It seems I have two options.  Option 1 would have me creating a custom initializer in the custom class.

Custom Initializer in custom class

```
init(dictionary : [String:String]) { self.URLDictionary = dictionary }
```

The process is the same as in Objective-C.

```
let URLTempDictionary = [kFLOCyclingURL : "FLO Cycling", kTriathleteURL : "Triathlete", kVeloNewsURL : "Velo News", kCyclingNewsURL : "Cycling News", kRoadBikeActionURL : "Road Bike Action", kIronmanURL : "Ironman"]

    var tempDataHandler = FLODataHandler(dictionary: URLTempDictionary)
    self.dataHandler! = tempDataHandler
```

Option 2 does not through a complaint but seems incomplete.

Instead of creating a custom initializer I would simply do the following.  The custom class has a dictionary property called URLDictionary.

```
let URLTempDictionary = [kFLOCyclingURL : "FLO Cycling", kTriathleteURL : "Triathlete", kVeloNewsURL : "Velo News", kCyclingNewsURL : "Cycling News", kRoadBikeActionURL : "Road Bike Action", kIronmanURL : "Ironman"]

self.dataHandler!.URLDictionary = URLTempDictionary
self.dataHandler.delegate = self
```

So my question has to do with the need for the custom initializer and the use of

```
var tempDataHandler = FLODataHandler(dictionary: URLTempDictionary)
```

Does the use of

```
self.dataHandler!.URLDictionary = URLTempDictionary
```

accomplish the same result?

Take care,

Jon

Comment: Could you let me know how you have declared dataHandler member in your class?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of an initializer is effectively to *compel* the caller to supply the data - and Swift helps you by enforcing this contract in a way that Objective-C does not. If you declare `init(dictionary:)`, all other inherited initializers cease to be inherited, and `init(dictionary:)` becomes the *only* way to make a FLODataHandler.

So if it is crucial that a FLODataHandler have a `URLDictionary` value from the get-go, by all means declare the initializer. Indeed, if it is crucial that it also have a delegate, declare `init(dictionary:delegate:)` instead. That is "best practice".

On the other hand, there is nothing inherently evil about two-stage initialization, i.e. first make the object, then give its properties values; and there are situations in real-life iOS programming where there's no real alternative (`prepareForSegue` comes to mind). The problem with it is that it relies on an unenforceable contract, which the caller must simply know in some other way and adhere to voluntarily.

EDIT: You also seem to be asking whether merely saying

```
self.dataHandler!.URLDictionary = URLTempDictionary
```

somehow magically creates a FLODataHandler to occupy the `dataHandler` property. It most certainly does not. No objects come magically into existence in Swift, any more than in Objective-C. If no one has ever said `FLODataHandler(...)`, then no such instance exists. If no one has ever assigned a FLODataHandler instance to `self.dataHandler`, then there is no FLODataHandler there (and the above code will crash if it means you are trying to unwrap `nil`).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  That makes a lot of sense.  One follow up question.  

In Objective-C we have to specifically call alloc and init and then pass the object to the property.  Is this not the case in Swift?  Does the line self.dataHandler!.URLDictionary = URLTempDictionary cover the creation of the new object?

Comment: No it does not. But it seems to me that that is a completely different matter. We are talking about how the data handler acquires a dictionary, not how to instantiate in the first place.

Comment: I will add a note about that to my answer.

Comment: It might help you to read the relevant part of my Swift book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_initializers

Comment: Please ignore my last comment.  I was wrong.  I see what needs to happen now.  I do have to initialize the object.  Thanks for all the help.